# Docker run --entrypoint with multiple parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, entry-point

I'm trying to understand a discrepancy between `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile and `docker run --entrypoint`. The `exec` form of `ENTRYPOINT` allows multiple parameters,

```
# Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

but `docker run --entrypoint=executable` accepts only one. Many examples show how to override `ENTRYPOINT` with arguments, but they do so by also specifying `CMD`:

```
docker run --entrypoint=executable image:latest param1 param2
```

Is there a technical limitation preventing a direct `docker run --entrypoint` equivalent to `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`? Docker Compose seems to support it with

```yaml
# Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#entrypoint
entrypoint: ["php", "-d", "memory_limit=-1", "vendor/bin/phpunit"]
```

as do other providers which work with Docker (e.g. AWS ECS). Or perhaps, internally, `[...entrypoint_args, ...command_args]` is actually massaged into `[entrypoint, ...command]` to make it compatible with `docker run`?

Comment: (This is a good reason to prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` for routine use, IMHO.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Docker cli uses the Golang CLI manager [spf13/cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) to handle its flags such as `--entrypoint`.

[This](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/88c6089300a82d3373892adf6845a4fed1a4ba8d/cli/command/container/opts.go#L177) is where the entrypoint is extracted:

```golang
flags.StringVar(&copts.entrypoint, "entrypoint", "", "Overwrite the default ENTRYPOINT of the image")
```

`StringVar` from the [spf13/pflag](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#StringVar) library will only extract the first string after the flag due to how it parses command line arguments. So it won't get all strings after the flag  if they're separated by spaces or not enclosed in double quotes `"`. So this seems to be that technical limitation.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Sounds like this technical limitation is limited to the `docker` CLI, and does not affect other alternatives (e.g. the Docker Engine API).

Comment: @mxxk Yes, exactly. The CLI just populates the same struct and the underlying type that sets the config is a string slice but the CLI always passes it a string: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v1.13.1/api/types/container/config.go#L54